# Get Error loading data from server:HTTP 200 after config parsoid and Visual Editor

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor, parsoid

Tring to setup a Visual Edtior in 192.168.20.130

I use apt-get to install parsoid and set config.yaml with

---

uri: 'http://192.168.20.130/wiki/api.php'

---

I tried to access 192.168.20.130:8142 via browser and got a working page.

Then I config LocalSettings.php with

---

```
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );    
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;

$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';    

$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(    
'url' => 'h*ttp://192.168.20.130:8142',//ignore this * pls due to stack overflow don't let me upload question descript with links

'domain' => '192.168.20.130',    
'prefix' => '192.168.20.130'    
);
```

---

After these config, I try to edit index page with Visual Editor but got a "Error loading data from server:HTTP 200"

I checked apache access_log and find this edit action request url:http://192.168.20.130/wiki/api.php?action=visualeditor&format=json&paction=parse&page=%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5&uselang=zh-cn (I use zh-cn and "%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5" is uri coding for index page), then I access this url manually but only got a message:"Exception encountered, of type "Error""

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can have a look at [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question better. This will help others to find out what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is `"Exception encountered, of type "Error""` on the action=visualeditor API. You need to look through your web server's error log to find exactly what went wrong there.